# javascript regular expression of minimum 3 words and allow special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that validates if it's a minimum of 3 words:

```
 "minimumThreeWordsAndNoURL": {
                    "regex": /^(\b\w+\b\s?){3,}$/,
                    "alertText": "Too short"
                },
```

Now the issue is that when I do 'How much is this?' it fails because of the special characters. How do I allow special characters in this regex?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should work:

```
^(?:(?:^| )\S+ *){3,}$
```

#### Online [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xI2sL1)

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
 /(\b\S+.*?){3,}/.test('How much is this?')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this untested:

```
(\b.{3,}\b\s)+
```